# Setting one of the columns in default value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there anyway to set as default value one of the columns or more in SQL Server? I normally use as default value for date only ex: `getdate()` but I haven’t tried other columns.

Example:

```
ID Name    Address Remarks
1  Richard USA     Name: Richard,Address: USA
```

I want to concatenate Name and Address as default value or bindings of Remarks. Tried ‘Name: ’ + [Name] + ‘,‘ + ‘Address: ’+[Address] it doesn’t work.

Comment: Does it need to be editable? Or can it be computed? You can't have a default that depends on other values that are part of the insert...

Comment: Oh, ok. So, I don’t have any choice but to use trigger after insert and update the Remarks field.

Comment: That looks like you want a *computed column* not a default value. If you *did* want to be able to change the value of `Remarks` and *not* `Address`/`Name`, then you have a design problem; `Remarks` is denormalised and you should be fixing that

Comment: Hi @DaleK how accurate and guaranteed trigger? Is there an instance trigger doesn’t capture whatever defined inside of it?

Comment: Also a `DEFAULT` `CONSTRAINT` can't be based on the values of other columns in the row; if you required that sort of logic it would normally be handled at the point of `INSERT`, such as in the Stored Procedure.

Comment: @ThomA my current approach is using trigger after insert it carries out SET UPDATE for Remarks concatenating Name and Address but since I have other trigger for after UPDATE it will trigger this event also which I want to get rid of as it floods up unnecessary records.

Comment: *Why* do you want to store the data, from the `Address` and `Name` columns in another column? What does it solve? Why would the value in the `Remarks` column *change* when the `Name`/`Address` doesn't?

Comment: @ThomA I will use it as original or raw data even the Name and Address are changed multiple times I can always go back to the original data as reference just like saying a history. Anyway, it seems not possible, thus I’d stick with my trigger after insert approach.

Comment: Then store those values as different columns called `OriginalName` and `OriginalAddress`. Then you can just pass your `@Name` and `@Address` (or whatever they are called) parameters to those columns too. `Remarks` as it is now, if *not* a good column; as I stated it is denormalised. I can also see you coming to [so] in a few days/weeks/months and asking "How do I get the values `'Richard'` and `'USA'` from the string `'Name: Richard,Address: USA'`?

Comment: @ThomA I can handle it in the front -end though but what I wanted is that in case the data is inserted directly from the backend at least it will still capture as default value. Anyway, I just decided to stick with the trigger after insert and delete the unnecessary records behind the scene. Thank you.

Comment: Looking forward to your new question in a couple of years/months: "how do i split a remarks field into name and address so i can access old data"

Comment: @siggemannen I can handle it in the front-end though. But thank you for being sarcastic, really appreciate it.

Comment: Sorry, just trying to steer you in a better direction, there's been a glut of "string split" questions here lately

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly set computed columns based on other column values within the `DEFAULT` constraint. You can achieve this using *computed* columns or *triggers* to generate a dynamic value based on other column values.

Computed Column Method:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    ID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    Address NVARCHAR(50),
    Remarks AS ('Name: ' + Name + ', Address: ' + Address)
)

INSERT INTO YourTable (ID, Name, Address)
VALUES (1, 'Richard', 'USA'), (2, 'Amit', 'India');
```

Trigger Method:

```
CREATE TABLE YourTable (
    ID INT,
    Name NVARCHAR(50),
    Address NVARCHAR(50),
    Remarks NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

CREATE TRIGGER SetRemarks ON YourTable
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE YourTable
    SET Remarks = 'Name: ' + INSERTED.Name + ', Address: ' + INSERTED.Address
    FROM YourTable
    INNER JOIN INSERTED ON YourTable.ID = INSERTED.ID
END

INSERT INTO YourTable (ID, Name, Address)
VALUES (1, 'Richard', 'USA'), (2, 'Amit', 'India');
```

Comment: Hi Amit, that’s my current approach though but since I have other trigger for after UPDATE this will affect, thus unnecessary records are created. So I was thinking to do it in default value instead. But since it seems not possible I just stick with my approach and delete the unnecessary records behind the scene.

Comment: You probably want a few `GO`s in there for clarity on where one batch should end and the next begins.